# How to use styles.module.scss to apply the customized styling in react-big-calendar

Tags: typescript, next.js, sass, momentjs, react-big-calendar

I'm using `react-big-calendar` library to create calendar, and I'm stuck with customizing the style of calendar and the SCSS is not applying

```
export const JobnsCalendar = () => (
  <Calendar
    className={styles.calendar}
    localizer={localizer}
    views={['month']}
    style={{ height: '80vh' }}
    formats={formats}
    components={{
      toolbar: Toolbar,
    }}
  />
);
```

`styles.module.scss` :

```
.calendar {
  .rbc-time-header-gutter,
  .rbc-time-content > .rbc-row > div:not(.rbc-time-gutter),
  .rbc-header,
  .rbc-month-view {
    border-right: none !important;
  }

  .rbc-month-view .rbc-row:not(.rbc-header-row) > .rbc-day:nth-child(6) {
    background-color: blue;
  }

  .rbc-month-view .rbc-row:not(.rbc-header-row) > .rbc-day:nth-child(7) {
    background-color: red;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All of the `rbc-` prefixed classes you reference are 'global' classes in Big Calendar, defined in the style sheet you must still be included in your interface, as that is how Big Calendar references them as they are applied. Your scss module would need to show that.

```scss
.calendar {
  :global(.rbc-time-header-gutter),
  // etc
}
```